Cannot view the word document but can download it when using https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=${data} in laravel
I can download the docs just fine but i cannot view it because this error showed up
An error occurred
We're sorry, but for some reason we can't open this for you
Learn More
When clicked Learn More
The webpage at https://www.office.com/redir.aspx?assetid=HA102724036 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
this is my current code
<div v-else>
        <div class="text-right mb-2">
          <a :href="data" @click="$emit('download')" target="_blank" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
        </div>
        <iframe :src="`https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=${data}`" width='100%' height="680px" frameborder='0'>This is an embedded <a target='_blank' href='http://office.com'>Microsoft Office</a> document, powered by <a target='_blank' href='http://office.com/webapps'>Office Online</a>.</iframe>
      </div>


